# I don't understand why this function isn't working

Tags: c++, function

So this is a simple text-based game I'm creating, starting with a menu. 
I want people to be able to play the game when they press 'p', but this play function isn't working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void menu()
{
char menuResponse;
cout << "[P]lay [O]ptions [C]redits\n";
cin >> menuResponse;
if (menuResponse == 'p')
{
    game();
}
else if (menuResponse == 'o')
{
    cout << "There's actually nothing to see here, sorry.\n";
    char optionResponse;
    cout << "[B]ack\n";
    cin >> optionResponse;
    menu();
}
else if (menuResponse == 'c')
{
    cout << "Created by Crusader Studios, 2014\n";
    char creditResponse;
    cout << "[B]ack\n";
    cin >> creditResponse;
    menu();
}
else
{
    cout << "Please type a valid letter.\n";
    menu();
}
}

void game()
{
    cout << "\t\t\tPrologue\n\n";
}
int main()
{
    cout << "\t\tWelcome to my first game, 'A Hero's Journey!'\n\n";
    cout << "To navigate through menus, type the letters inside the brackets. For            example,\n";
    cout << "pressing 'p' in a menu with [P]lay and [O]ptions will let you play.\n\n";
    char beginResponse;
    cout << "Do you understand? If so, press any key:\n";
    cin >> beginResponse;
    cout << "Great! Now we can begin our game!\n";
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

The function for playing the game is void game() and the menu is void menu().

Comment: what is the problem here... were you able to compile the code..

Comment: It told me there were build errors, and no.

Comment: declare the `void game();`

Comment: I don't know why people downvote without comments.

Comment: As long as my question was answered, I'm fine. Thanks a lot, by the way, guys.

Comment: " isn't working." isn't a good description and doesn't help anyone else to help you ... say what actually *is* happening, and if it's not perfectly clear, say what you expected to happen instead. If there are error messages then paste those in.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared the function...

```
void game();
```

declare it before `void menu()` function

```
void game();
void menu()
{
//... code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I thought it didn't matter what order functions were placed in. Haven't used C++ in a few years, my first 'game' creation too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give prototype of function before using it, for that we need to mostly use header files in C/C++.

So before using,
if (menuResponse == 'p')
{
    game();
}

You should, declare prototype.

```
void game();
....
if (menuResponse == 'p')
{
    game();
}
```